# Massive performance slowdown when changing int to unsigned long long in segmented sieve

Tags: c, performance, sieve-of-eratosthenes, unsigned-long-long-int

I'm confused about the performance of my `C` program that implements a [Segmented Sieve](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/segmented-sieve/). I originally used only `int` as the datatype but to support bigger numbers I decided to switch to `unsigned long long`. I expected some performance penalty due to overhead, but when I try the segmented sieve with upper limit 100 billion, the `int` approach takes 23 seconds whereas the `unsigned long long` doesn't even finish (or at least takes too long for me to wait)

here's the segmented sieve with just `int` datatype, with N (upper bound) preset to 100B-

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdbool.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<time.h>

int size = 5;
int current_slot = 0;
int* primes_arr;

void append(int data)
{
    if ((current_slot + 1) < size)
    {
        primes_arr[current_slot++] = data;
        return;
    }
    int* newarr = realloc(primes_arr, (size += 5) * sizeof(int));
    if (newarr != NULL)
    {
        newarr[current_slot++] = data;
        primes_arr = newarr;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\nAn error occured while re-allocating memory\n");
        exit(1);
    }
}

// The following is just a standard approach to segmented sieve, nothing interesting

void simpleSieve(int limit)
{
    int p;
    if (primes_arr == NULL)
    {
        printf("\nAn error occured while allocating primes_arr for mark in simpleSieve\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    bool* mark = malloc((limit + 1) * sizeof(bool));
    if (mark != NULL)
    {
        memset(mark, true, sizeof(bool) * (limit + 1));
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\nAn error occured while allocating memory for mark in simpleSieve\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    for (p = 2; p * p < limit; p++)
    {
        if (mark[p])
        {
            for (int i = p * 2; i < limit; i += p)
            {
                mark[i] = false;
            }
        }
    }

    for (p = 2; p < limit; p++)
    {
        if (mark[p])
        {
            append(p);
            // printf("%d ", p);
        }
    }
}

void segmentedSieve(int n)
{
    int limit = (int)floor(sqrt(n)) + 1;
    simpleSieve(limit);

    int low = limit;
    int high = 2 * limit;

    while (low < n)
    {
        if (high >= n)
        {
            high = n;
        }
        bool* mark = malloc((limit + 1) * sizeof(bool));
        if (mark != NULL)
        {
            memset(mark, true, sizeof(bool) * (limit + 1));
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\nAn error occured while allocating memory for mark in segmentedSieve\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < current_slot; i++)
        {
            int lower_lim = (int)floor(low / primes_arr[i]) * primes_arr[i];
            if (lower_lim < low)
            {
                lower_lim += primes_arr[i];
            }
            for (int j = lower_lim; j < high; j += primes_arr[i])
            {
                mark[j - low] = false;
            }
        }

        for (int i = low; i < high; i++)
        {
            if (mark[i - low] == true)
            {
                // printf("%d ", i);
            }
        }
        low = low + limit;
        high = high + limit;
        free(mark);
    }
}

int main()
{
    primes_arr = malloc(size * sizeof(int));
    clock_t t0 = clock();
    segmentedSieve(100000000000);
    clock_t t1 = clock();
    double time_taken = (double) (t1 - t0) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("\nDone! Time taken: %f\n", time_taken);
    return 0;
}
```

and here's the segmented sieve with just `unsigned long long` datatype, with N (upper bound) preset to 100B-

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdbool.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<time.h>

unsigned long size = 5, current_slot = 0;
unsigned long long* primes_arr;

void append(unsigned long long data)
{
    if ((current_slot + 1) < size)
    {
        primes_arr[current_slot++] = data;
        return;
    }
    unsigned long long* newarr = realloc(primes_arr, (size += 5l) * sizeof(unsigned long long));
    if (newarr != NULL)
    {
        newarr[current_slot++] = data;
        primes_arr = newarr;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\nAn error occured while re-allocating memory\n");
        exit(1);
    }
}

void simpleSieve(unsigned long limit)
{
    unsigned long long p;
    if (primes_arr == NULL)
    {
        printf("\nAn error occured while allocating primes_arr for mark in simpleSieve\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    bool* mark = malloc((limit + 1) * sizeof(bool));
    if (mark == NULL)
    {
        printf("\nAn error occured while allocating memory for mark in segmentedSieve\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    memset(mark, true, sizeof(bool) * (limit + 1));

    for (p = 2; p * p < limit; p++)
    {
        if (mark[p])
        {
            for (unsigned long long i = p * 2; i < limit; i += p)
            {
                mark[i] = false;
            }
        }
    }

    for (p = 2; p < limit; p++)
    {
        if (mark[p])
        {
            append(p);
            //printf("%llu ", p);
        }
    }
}

void segmentedSieve(unsigned long long n)
{
    unsigned long limit = (unsigned long)floor(sqrt(n)) + 1l;
    simpleSieve(limit);

    unsigned long low = limit;
    unsigned long high = 2 * limit;

    while (low < n)
    {
        if (high >= n)
        {
            high = n;
        }
        bool* mark = malloc((limit + 1) * sizeof(bool));
        if (mark == NULL)
        {
            printf("\nAn error occured while allocating memory for mark in segmentedSieve\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        memset(mark, true, sizeof(bool) * (limit + 1));
        for (unsigned long long i = 0; i < current_slot; i++)
        {
            unsigned long long lower_lim = (unsigned long)floor(low / primes_arr[i]) * primes_arr[i];
            if (lower_lim < low)
            {
                lower_lim += primes_arr[i];
            }
            for (unsigned long long j = lower_lim; j < high; j += primes_arr[i])
            {
                mark[j - low] = false;
            }
        }

        for (unsigned long long i = low; i < high; i++)
        {
            if (mark[i - low])
            {
                //printf("%llu ", i);
            }
        }
        low = low + limit;
        high = high + limit;
        free(mark);
    }
}

int main()
{
    primes_arr = malloc(size * sizeof(unsigned long long));
    clock_t t0 = clock();
    segmentedSieve(100000000000);
    clock_t t1 = clock();
    double time_taken = (double)(t1 - t0) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("\nDone! Time taken: %f\n", time_taken);
    return 0;
}
```

I fail to see *why* this is happening, am I doing something wrong?

Edit: I also realize that `int` shouldn't be capable of handling 100 billion anyway and yet the program executes with no errors and even prints the final time report. Meanwhile the `unsigned long long` program doesn't even finish in **double** the time it takes for the `int` one.

On the other hand, trying to set the upper bound to 1B on both, actually return pretty similar results. Why?

Comment: Note that the use of global variables is considered bad practice.

Comment: 100 billion overflows the `int`.

Comment: @machine_1: Yep - would overflow the `int`, probably wrap around to a much smaller value, then be fast because it doesn't do most of the work.

Comment: The `int` data type overflows at alittle above 2 billion. Run your program with `int` and `unsigned long long` for 3 billion limit and compare results. It is possible that `unsigned long long` takes so long because there really are so many calculations to do, and `int` calculates a bogus result, so it's fast. If your `int` version outputs a correct result much faster, then you have a real question, and a real performance measurement. In the case of 100 billion, "23 seconds" vs "too long for me to wait" is not a useful measurement.

Comment: Integer overflow may not cause a run-time error, but it *will* cause incorrect results. Check the answers (in `primes_arr`?) when you use the 'int' version with 100 billion, and you'll probably see what's going on.

Comment: An array of bool is an array of char. You can save a factor of 8 in memory usage  by doing your own bit-fiddling.

Comment: I see, that makes sense, but apart from that is the code itself fine? I'm especially concerned about `memset` and `limit`, will those work even in the biggest number without overflow cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

100 billion decimally is 17 4876 E800<sub>H</sub> hexadecimally. As it doesn't fit into `int`, the 'surplus' most significant bits are cut away, remaining 4876 4800<sub>H</sub>, which is 1.215.752.192<sub>D</sub>, so you actually set the limit to just a 100th of what you actually intended when calling `segmentedSieve` within `main`.

Actually, you have been lucky not to produce a negative number that way.

Be aware, though, that you have entered the land of *undefined behaviour* due to signed integer overflow. Anything could have happened, including your programme crashing or switching off the sun...

Far more interesting, though, have a look at the following:

```
segmentedSieve(unsigned long long n)
{
    unsigned long low = limit;
    while (low < n)
```

That's critical. On many systems, `long` has the same size as `int` (with e. g. 64-bit linux being an exception). If that's the case on *your* system as well, then you produce an en endless loop, as `low` will just overflow, too, (solely that it's not undefined behaviour this time) and won't ever be able to reach your 100 billion stored in `n`...

You should use `unsigned long long` consistently – or maybe even better, `uint64_t` from `stdint.h`.

Comment: I'd like to use `unsinged long long` in all of those, however I was concerned about `memset`. Will `memset` work with `unsigned long long`?